# Specifiying sensor for Google Maps Javascript API when using W3C Geolocation

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

When using the Google Maps JavaScript API V3 do I need to specify `sensor` as `true` when I'm getting the user's location using W3C Geolocation? It does obviously work even without specifying it (because that part of the code has nothing to do with the API).

I'm interested in both whether or not Google wants me to specify it and whether or not I actually need to specify it.

(Besides for the fact that the `sensor` parameter seems pointless anyway, or is there just a point that I'm missing?)